# Perl Matching Special Characters

Tags: regex, perl, special-characters

I am trying to do a simple match like:

```
if ($variable ne '*') { print "Hello"; }
```

I want to match everything not equal to the "*" character (no quotations)

But I am not sure if I need to use a backslash before the * or if I should use the forward slash regex notation I see for other solutions. What is the best solution here?

Here is a sample code:

```
if ($var ne '*') { print "it is not a star!"; }
else 
{ 
    $var = '*';
    print "made $var into a star!"
}
```

Is that right for setting a variable to be a * character?

Comment: Do you mean if * is not contained in $variable ? If you don't then what you have is ok.

Comment: Isn't this something that you could check for yourself very easily? `perl -le '$var = "foo"; print "yes" if $var ne "*"'` Or try `perl -nle 'print "Hello" if $_ ne "*"'`

Comment: As said, you could try to run your code. If a little foggy, you may want read up on quoting in perl and perl operators as well.

Comment: My favorite is `$var = '*';` why bother checking?

Comment: This is just a massive oversimplification, it makes no sense in this context you are correct.

Comment: Dan, your sample code sets `$var` to a star if `$var` is a star.

Answer (score 2):

You'd only need to escape the '*' character if you were using a regular expression match, but since you're using a directly comparison (with `ne`) then your code is fine. If you *were* using a regex, then you'd say:

```
if ($variable !~ /^\*$/) { ... }
```

But in this case, using `ne` is clearer and quicker, I imagine.

For completeness, you can also use `\Q` in regular expression to quote all metacharacters until a `\E` is encountered. So:

```
if ($variable !~ /^\Q***\E$/ { ... }
```

would evaluate to true if the `$variable` was not equal to three '*' characters. But again, you'd be better off with:

```
if ($variable ne '***') { ... }
```

Comment: sorry i meant to continue that comment, my code looks like this:

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are looking for a regex.

```
if ($variable !~ /\*/) { print "Hello"; }
```